# decode mp3 from streaming URL

Tags: c, mp3, icecast, lame

I am trying to decode mp3 from icecast server but i am getting hip: bitstream problem, resyncing skipping 164 bytes... error. I am decoding using lame decoder.

```
hip_t hipVal;
hipVal = hip_decode_init();
while(1)
{
Readdatafromnet(ringBuf, (void**)&buffer);
sampleno = hip_decode(hipVal,buffer,irhandle->size, pcmrBuffer, pcmlBuffer);
player_write(handle, pcmrBuffer, sampleno);
}
hip_decode_exit(hipVal);
```

Comment: Consider upgrading the shown code to a [mre] please.

Comment: Are you requesting metadata interleaving/injection by setting the `Icy-MetaData` HTTP header? If yes, then you MUST de-interleave your data at the signalled `Icy-metaint` before you feed it to your decoder.

Comment: @TBR I am not requesting metadata

Comment: Do you get this error at the very beginning of your data stream?